# How to set the data by considering the columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame like

```
data={'x':[0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,0,0,0,0],'y':[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1],
  'subx':[0,1,2,3,0,1,2,3,0,1,2,3,0,1,2,3,0,1,2,3],'suby':[0,1,2,3,0,1,2,3,0,1,2,3,0,1,2,3,0,1,2,3],
  'data':[10,20,10,10,11,13,13,15,12,13,14,12,14,12,12,13,11,20,14,47]}
```

I want create a table like this;

```
 df=pd.DataFrame(data)
 table=pd.pivot_table(data=df,index=['y','suby'],columns=['x','subx'],values= 
       ['data'],aggfunc='count')
```

Currentoutput:

```
        data                                ...                                   
x         0                   1            ...    2              3               
subx      0    1    2    3    0    1    2  ...    1    2    3    0    1    2    3
y suby                                     ...                                   
0 0     1.0  NaN  NaN  NaN  1.0  NaN  NaN  ...  NaN  NaN  NaN  1.0  NaN  NaN  NaN
  1     NaN  1.0  NaN  NaN  NaN  1.0  NaN  ...  1.0  NaN  NaN  NaN  1.0  NaN  NaN
  2     NaN  NaN  1.0  NaN  NaN  NaN  1.0  ...  NaN  1.0  NaN  NaN  NaN  1.0  NaN
  3     NaN  NaN  NaN  1.0  NaN  NaN  NaN  ...  NaN  NaN  1.0  NaN  NaN  NaN  1.0
1 0     1.0  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  ...  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
  1     NaN  1.0  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  ...  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
  2     NaN  NaN  1.0  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  ...  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
  3     NaN  NaN  NaN  1.0  NaN  NaN  NaN  ...  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
```

Requirement: It does not fill the data values in the corresponding positions instead of 1's

```
  output: 
  
x         0                   1            ...
subx      0    1    2    3    0    1    2  ... 
y suby                                     ...
0 0     10  NaN  NaN  NaN  11  NaN  NaN  ...
  1     NaN  20  NaN  NaN  NaN  13  NaN  ... 
  2     NaN  NaN  10  NaN  NaN  NaN  13  ... 
  3     NaN  NaN  NaN  10  NaN  NaN  NaN  ... 
1 0     11  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  ...  
  1     NaN  20  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  ... 
  2     NaN  NaN  14  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  ...  
  3     NaN  NaN  NaN  47  NaN  NaN  NaN  ...
```

Answer (score 1):

Is the shape what you expected? Then you can just add

```
pd.pivot_table(..., fill_value=0)
```

`pivot_table` will leave every field blank if the combination of indices did not exist in your original dataframe

```
In [10]: pd.pivot_table(
    ...:     data=df,
    ...:     index=["y", "suby"],
    ...:     columns=["x", "subx"],
    ...:     values=["data"],
    ...:     aggfunc="count",
    ...:     fill_value=0,
    ...: )
Out[10]: 
       data                                             
x         0           1           2           3         
subx      0  1  2  3  0  1  2  3  0  1  2  3  0  1  2  3
y suby                                                  
0 0       1  0  0  0  1  0  0  0  1  0  0  0  1  0  0  0
  1       0  1  0  0  0  1  0  0  0  1  0  0  0  1  0  0
  2       0  0  1  0  0  0  1  0  0  0  1  0  0  0  1  0
  3       0  0  0  1  0  0  0  1  0  0  0  1  0  0  0  1
1 0       1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
  1       0  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
  2       0  0  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
  3       0  0  0  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
```

Comment: needs to fill the last column 'data' values inside the output